# Unity Web Player games - Facebook removed

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

> Please Use a Different Browser to Play XY Game
>
> On Tuesday, April 14th, 2015, Google Chrome removed the ability to play Unity Web Player games. XY game, can still be played on Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari. If you'd like to continue to play Facebook Games using Google Chrome, please select another game.

I'm working on a game with friend and he's using Unity. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity 5.x currently has 'preview' support for WebGL. This is the direction Unity is moving for it's web publishing. Its is probably the best option available at this time, but it's still not great. They discuss this in this [Unity Blog Post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/28/web-publishing-following-chrome-npapi-deprecation/).

Unity has documentation on [Getting Started with WebGL Development](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html). It does currently have some limitations and may or may not be feasible depending on what features the game needs.

Unity WebGL builds currently don't support:

> - Runtime generation of Substance textures
> - MovieTextures
> - Networking other then WWW class
> - Support for WebCam and Microphone access
> - Most of the non-basic audio features (anything beyond basic positional playback of audio is not supported).
> - Script debugging
> - Threads
> - Any .NET features requiring dynamic code generation (just as on other AOT platforms like iOS)
> - Runtime GI

It's a shame in the timing. Google is really doing the right thing by disabling NPAPI for security reasons, but it's a shame that there's not equivalent alternative at the moment.

Comment: Also take a look at Facebook's documentation of Unity deployment to the web. WebGL is covered and there is now a webinar embedded covering best practices. Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas